# How to calculate the numerical integral of the type $\int_a^b e^{x^2}dx$ efficiently?

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

How to calculate the numerical integral of the type  $ \int_a^b e^{x^2} dx $ efficiently?

My problem is:

we need to compute repeatly the integral:

$$ \frac{\int_{|m|=1}mm \exp(B\mathbin:mm)\,dm}{\int_{|m|=1}\exp(B\mathbin:mm)\,dm}$$ where

1. $:$ means $A\mathbin:B=\sum_{i,j}A(i,j)*B(j,i)$
2. m is a 1 dimensional tensor, $m \in R^{1\times 3}$
3. B is a traceless diagonalizable two dimensional  tensor.
4. $mm$ means the tensor product $m \otimes m$

Comment: Is the result meant to be a tensor, or a numeric value?  (i.e., is the mm outside of the exponential a tensor product or a dot product?)

Comment: It's a tensor. It's proved it can be diagonalized by the same matrix as B.